# How can a button be not announced as "button" by screenreader when it reads it?

Tags: accessibility, jaws-screen-reader

I have HTML buttons and want them to not be announced as buttons by the screen reader. Is there a way for it? I am using the button for Rating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What kind of object would you like it announced as?  When you have a "ratings" type object, doesn't the user have to click on it to set the rating?  So, for example, if you have 5 possible stars and the user wants to give it a rating of 4 stars, don't they have to click on the 4th star?  The act of clicking needs to be conveyed to screen readers too.

Instead of having 5 single "buttons", it could be a radio group with 5 radio buttons.  Or I suppose it could be a "slider".  But whatever object you think is appropriate, the role of that object needs to be announced so that the screen reader user knows how to interact with it.  When a screen reader user hears "button", they know they can press <kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> on it to select it.  If they hear "radio button" or "slider", they know they can use the arrow keys to change the selection.

I would go with a radio group and radio buttons since your rating will be a mutually exclusive set of X objects that you can only choose one of.

For an example, see https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/forms/custom-controls/#a-star-rating

Comment: Thank you for the useful insight. I was unclear on the subject. but is there any way we can not announce button as "button" by screen reader using role or something else

Comment: Yes, as I described above.  You probably want radio roles.  Look at the example on w3.org site.